# Export table to .dat file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My database got a problem. So i need to export a table content to .dat file with insert query then sending it to an expert. However i could only export to sql extension. Is there anyway to solve that problems. 
Thanks.
I'm using Oracle Developer tool. I'vê tried many methods but it seems to get no answer

Comment: Rename the file from `.sql` to `.dat`?

Answer (score 0):

What is a .DAT version? Personally, I'd export it using **Export** data pump (or the original EXP utility, regarding the fact that you're exporting a single table). Your *expert* would then import it into his own database.

If you are talking about series of `INSERT` INTO statements, boy, that might take ages to both export and import, if a table is large. Anyway, as it is a pure TXT file, you can change its extension from .SQL to .DAT (or .XYZ or whatever you want, it will still be a textual file).